# How to send video clip and image attachments using jms/activemq?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have a requirement to send MMS messages which have attachments (images/video clips) using the JMS/ActiveMQ broker. I have looking several examples on JMS messaging but all they use is a "text message" to demo. How would I send the MMS messages?

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. If not, please elaborate as to why. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [`javax.jms.TextMessage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/TextMessage.html) is just one of several types of [`javax.jms.Message`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html) implementations supported by JMS. I recommend you convert your MMS data into a byte array and send it using a [`javax.jms.BytesMessage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html).